# Inheritance but with two different shared traits?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, inheritance, class-design, class

I am facing a dilemma with designing an api gateway. Currently, I am using the pipeline pattern, with different stages being the requests made to various services, (http, sockets, amqp, ...).

I have a base class, RequestStage, with some subclasses, HttpStage, SocketStage, AmqpStage. These classes extend RequestStage because they can have different unique parameters for each of their requests.

The problem is that each stage/event (subclass) must be a call either to a middleware api or downstream api. If it is a middleware api, then there should be a fail response condition to short circuit the pipeline.

How can I fit this extra field/trait in? If the stage/event class is calling a middleware api request, then it should contain an extra field "failCondition", but how could I implement this cleanly since my inheritance is based on request protocol type and not service type?

Comment: Inheritance doesn't sound like the right tool for the job here - AMQP and HTTP have fundamentally different semantics to each other (totally different communication patterns).    What specific problem are you trying to solve in this attempt to build a unified abstraction?       I would think a much better solution would be to separate both of these out entirely and abandon any attempts to unify them.   i.e. one API gateway for your HTTP service and another completely separate unrelated API gateway for your AMQP service.

Comment: Which of the many search  results for “pipeline pattern” should I assume you’re using?

Comment: @candied_orange something like this: https://michaelscodingspot.com/pipeline-pattern-implementations-csharp/

Comment: @BenCottrell The idea was to create a central gateway that handles protocol translation for all my downstream services (rest -> socket, rest -> grpc, etc), so that's why I am trying to build with all the protocols together

Comment: @hotswappable Do you really need a unified interface / inheritance heirarchy though?  For example, could you have a separate REST endpoint for AMQP handled in an unrelated class compared with some of the others?   Keeping in mind that the communication patterns/semantics of these different mechanisms are fundamentally a long way apart from each other,  i.e they have so few things in common that any abstraction would likely only be able to offer an extremely limited capability, and would throw away most of the benefits of using them in the first place.

Comment: @BenCottrell that is a good idea I will try that thanks! want to post it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I will implement the gateway with multiple endpoints to handle various protocols vs abstracting them together